# VB6's Boolean data type equivalent in MIDL

Tags: vb6, midl

Which MIDL data type is equal to the VB6's `Boolean` type?

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367090%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) `Boolean` is available in MIDL.

Comment: Thanks! The `VARIANT_BOOL` data type is just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I tried `Boolean` (as @Sohnee suggested), `VARIANT_BOOL` (thanks to @Alex K.) and `BOOL`.

The `Boolean` type was not recognized by VB6's Object Browser. The `VARIANT_BOOL` is the exact equivalent to a VB6's `Boolean` data type. The `BOOL` was recognizes as `Long` data type in VB6.